# how to handle variable column headers (row location) in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We ingest data from multiple customers and have no control over the format of the data. The data pertains to the same subject matter but the file names, column names, headers, and row headings are all variable.
Schema drift capabilities in data flow mapping looks like it will handle the variable file and column names but i'm not sure how best to handle the fact that the column headings could be on row 1 or 2 or 10, etc.
Previously we used some Python code to figure this out, is there any capability within Data Factory to accommodate this level of variability?

Comment: @KranthiPakala-MSFT While your edits did add relevant tags, please make sure to also fix issues inside the question (grammar, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You will need a rule to determine which row has the headers. Then, you can use a Filter transform to filter out the header row from the data rows.

But if you need the names of the headers in your flow, then you'll need to first run that file through a separate data flow that rewrites the file with the header row as the first row.

You can do this by adding 2 sources to a data flow, both pointing to the same file. Then, filter OUT the header row from one source and filter IN just the header row in the 2nd source.

Union those 2 streams back together and write to a new file in the Sink.